# What is the word for a Road Sign that shows direction

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

What is the right word for the signs in the highways that indicates the correct direction to another city or province for an example?

I thought about the word "road signs", but it is not what I am looking for because it does not imply guiding the driver to the way that leads to another city.

Comment: Are you talking about [arrows](http://www.roadtrafficsigns.com/arrow-traffic-signs)? If not, it may help to show an example of the type of sign you are referring to.

Comment: yes the arrows with some captions indicate the city u r travelling to

Comment: Ok, I'll turn my comment into an answer.

Comment: On second thoughts, it might be better to just have Josh61 add to his answer, especially with his recent edits :) .

Comment: This topic almost certainly has US/UK differences, and in the US there are likely several different "standards" among the various states.

Comment: @HotLicks By "standards", I assume you mean the format/appearance of the signs?  But would the name/word used to describe the *type* of sign change, e.g. 'direction sign'?

Comment: @TrevorD - I mean the terminology used in laws, records kept by the government, work orders to the highway crews, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are generally referred  to as ***[traffic signs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_sign)*** or road signs:

> - ***signs erected at the side of or above roads to give instructions or provide information to road users.*** The earliest signs were simple wooden or stone milestones. Later, signs with directional arms were introduced, for example, the fingerposts in the United Kingdom and their wooden counterparts in Saxony.

In your specific case you are probably referring to a:

## [direction sign](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction,_position,_or_indication_sign),

> - more fully defined as a direction, position, or indication sign by the Vienna Convention on Road Signs and Signals, ***is any road sign used primarily to give information about the location of either the driver or possible destinations, and are considered a subset of the informative signs group***. Direction signs are far more varied internationally than other classes of sign, as the Vienna Convention does not specify sizes, colours, symbols or positions of such signs.

[image]
(Wikipedia)

Comment: Feel free to use some of the terms from the link in my [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337652/what-is-the-word-for-the-road-sign-that-shows-direction?noredirect=1#comment776007_337652).

Answer (score 3):

Note that ***traffic sign*** is a general-purpose term that includes hazard warnings, speed limits, etc.

A sign telling you which road to take to get somewhere (or telling you where you'll end up if you continue on your present course) is more specifically called a...

> [**signpost**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/signpost) *- sign giving information such as the **direction and distance to a nearby town**, typically found at a road junction*